# How do I embed youtube video via url in frontend posting

Tags: images, media, front-end, videos

I would like to embed videos & images by entering url in my wordpress site. In WordPress repsitory there are many plugins for embed video by url but in my site I want to enable this functionality from frontend. Registered users can be able to enter a url  and this video will enbed in the post. How can I achieve this.

Comment: Video embeds are now innately supported by Wordpress core. I haven't done much with frontend submission, but do any of the frontend submission plugins now work with this inately as well?

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress supports quite a few [embeds](https://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds) including YouTube since [WordPress 2.9](https://codex.wordpress.org/Version_2.9).

To render anywhere, just pass your content through [`the_content`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) filter and it should automatically convert the urls.

```
$oembedContent = apply_filters( 'the_content', $basicContent );
```

If the defaults don't meet your needs you can add an oEmbed-Enabled site using [`wp_oembed_add_provider( $format, $provider, $regex )`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_oembed_add_provider) or add non oEmbed-Enabled sites using [`wp_embed_register_handler( $id, $regex, $callback, $priority )`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_embed_register_handler). [GenerateWP](https://generatewp.com/oembed/) includes a section to generate add_provider code.

To test them out, run your url through [`wp_oembed_get()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_oembed_get)

```
$embed_code = wp_oembed_get( $url, $args );
```

and filter the returned oEmbed HTML with [`oembed_dataparse`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/oembed_dataparse/). There is a good example of using [`oembed_dataparse`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/oembed_dataparse/) at [lorut](http://www.lorut.no/responsive-vimeo-youtube-embed-wordpress/) to make some video embeds responsive.

```
// Hook onto 'oembed_dataparse' and get 2 parameters
add_filter( 'oembed_dataparse', 'responsive_wrap_oembed_dataparse', 10, 2 );



function responsive_wrap_oembed_dataparse( $html, $data ) {
    // Verify oembed data (as done in the oEmbed data2html code)
    if ( ! is_object( $data ) || empty( $data->type ) ) {
        return $html;
    }

    // Verify that it is a video
    if ( ! ( $data->type == 'video' ) ) {
        return $html;
    }

    // Calculate aspect ratio
    $ar = $data->width / $data->height;

    // Set the aspect ratio modifier
    $ar_mod = ( abs( $ar - ( 4 / 3 ) ) < abs( $ar - ( 16 / 9 ) ) ? 'embed-responsive-4by3' : 'embed-responsive-16by9' );

    // Strip width and height from html
    $html = preg_replace( '/(width|height)="\d*"\s/', "", $html );

    // Return code
    return '<div class="embed-responsive ' . $ar_mod . '" data-aspectratio="' . number_format( $ar, 5, '.' ) . '">' . $html . '</div>';
}
```

WordPress 4.4 introduced a [oEmbed discovery](https://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds#What_About_oEmbed_Discovery.3F) to allow WP links to be embedded. [amaze.website](http://amaze.website/customizing-wordpress-embed-links-preview/) wrote an article on how to style your embeds using [`embed_head`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/embed_head/) and [`embed_footer`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/embed_footer/).

```
// Add custom footer after embed links preview
add_action( 'embed_footer', 'embed_custom_footer_line' );   
function embed_custom_footer_line(){ ?>
    <div id="custom-embed-footer">
        <h3>Our custom Footer line!</h3>
    </div>
<?php }
```

Answer (score -1):

I haven't used any of the frontend submission plugins, but there are a decent handful of them around. WPMU recently did an article: http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/wordpress-post-frontend-plugins/

- http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-submitted-posts/
- http://wordpress.org/plugins/front-end-publishing/
- http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-user-frontend/
- http://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-guest-post/
- http://wordpress.org/plugins/frontend-uploader/

I've not reviewed the community guidelines recently, but I think requests for plugin suggestions may actually be off-topic here.

Comment: I tried all these but No one give the functionality of video embed by url so I ask here is there any other way to enable this functionality from frontend

Comment: No, not directly. You'll need to use a plugin and adjust it to fit your needs.